# lines within TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to insert two parallel lines before and after part titles in the TOC (see the picture below). Is there and easy way to do it? I'm using  `\documentclass{book}`. How about inserting the lines before and after the section titles?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `titlesec/titletoc` which have a `\titlerule` command. Here is a way to obtain something (almost) close to the picture — I didn't want to hack for the appearance of ‘Contents’, which is not the main subject of your question.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
\def\contentsname{{C\MakeLowercase{ontents}}}

\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}}%
{}{\partname~}%% numbered/numberless formatting
{\hfill\contentspage}%% to be replaced with {} if you don't want any page number for parts
[\addvspace{0.7ex}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}]

      \titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\addvspace{2ex}\bfseries}%
      {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{0pt}\qquad}%numbered
      {}%numberless%
      {\hfill\contentspage}%

      \titlecontents{section}[3.4em]{\addvspace{1ex}\bfseries}%
      {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1em}\quad}%numbered
      {}%numberless%
      {\hfill\contentspage}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{INTRODUCTION}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{Background}
\section{Problem formulation}
\section{Outline}
\section{Contributions}

\chapter{PRELIMINARIES}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It is nice! The question is do I have to redefine my part, chapter and section styles (and their heading)? By the way, the parts should also have page numbers.

Comment: For the parts page numbers, there weren't in the picture, so I deleted them, but I'll change that in a moment. As for the re-definition of styles, do you mean the formatting in the toc, or the formatting in the body of the document?

Comment: without numbers is fine! Thanks! I think in your code I should add all the main lines before \begin{document} to my preamble, right? That's it?

Comment: Yes, just as I did. Btw I modified my example so that page numbers appear for parts (a comment explains how to do if you don't want them), and font size for parts is like the picture (I removed `\large` from the second mandatory argument).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to first modify my part style anyway and then use your code.

Comment: I suggest you use `titlesec` for that. If cooperates of course well with `titletoc` (same author). In the same bundle, `titleps` can replace `fancyhdr`.

Comment: I think I cannot follow you. I have a redefined style for my \chapter. I'd also like to define one for my \part. Does that affect how I'm going to use your codes? Maybe better to return to you after I modified my \part style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15908/discussion-between-bernard-and-latexquest).