# Solid line under each entry in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I am trying to recreate this table of contents formatting.

[image]

I've tried using the `titletoc` package and got this far. But I don't know how to make the line go underneath all the entries.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

\titlecontents{section}
  [1.5em]
  {}
  {\bfseries\color{blue}\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.5em}}
  {}
  {\titlerule[0.4pt]\bfseries\color{blue}{\contentspage}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\section{My First Section}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsubsection{Test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably a task for [etoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc?lang=en)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to add an additional square brackets at the end which you can put `addvspace` and `titlerule`.  see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192799/187447

```
\titlecontents{section}
  [1.5em]
  {}
  {\bfseries\color{blue}\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.5em}}%
  {}
  {\titlerule[0pt]\bfseries\color{blue}{\contentspage}}
  [\addvspace{0.5ex}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}]
```

[image]